# Flux Homomorphism has right inverse

Tags: symplectic-geometry

I'm reading about the Flux homomorphism in Symplectic Topology and I'm trying to show that it is surjective.

I know that if $\psi_{t}$ is the flow of a symplectic vector field $X$, then Flux({$\psi_{t}$}) = [$i(X) \omega$] (here $\omega$ is the symplectic form, so it must be nondegenerate) I'm trying to use this to construct a right inverse, but I don't really know how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix a class $[\alpha]\in H^{1}(M)$. Since $\omega$ is non-degenerate, there exists a unique vector field $X\in\mathfrak{X}(M)$ such that
$$
\iota_{X}\omega=\alpha.
$$
Since $\alpha$ is closed, the vector field $X$ is symplectic:
$$
L_{X}\omega=d\iota_{X}\omega+\iota_{X}d\omega=d\alpha=0.
$$
Let $\psi_{t}$ denote the flow of $X$, and denote by $\{\psi_t\}$ its homotopy class. Then
$$
Flux\{\psi_{t}\}=[\iota_{X}\omega]=[\alpha].
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is what I was missing!

Comment: Don't you need to check that this is well defined ? If you take another representative of the cohomology class and take the different flows generated by the vector fields that these are going to be homotopic ? @studiosus